# Excel - setting a dynamic print area for a range of cells covered by an array formula

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a page (Sheet 3) which I would like to export as a PDF (using a macro to export the pdf).

Currently, this links in to another worksheet, in which a user can put in a date range to pull out relevant data from a larger worksheet. This uses the following array formula to populate the data on Sheet 3:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$V$3:$W$5998,SMALL(IF((Sheet1!$C$3:$C$5998>=Crynodeb!$D$3)*(Sheet1!$C$3:$C$5998<=Crynodeb!$F$3)*(Sheet1!$V$3:$V$5998<>""),ROW(Sheet1!$V$3:$W$5998)-2),ROW(18:18)),1),"")
```

The array formula on Sheet 3 has been applied to around 6000 rows of data. So there is potential for 6000 lines of data to be returned. However, depending on the criteria the user has put in, maybe only 5 rows of data will be returned.

In addition to this, I've applied cell formatting to the 6000 rows so that there's a print-friendly line in between the rows of data.

However, because this has been applied to the 6000 rows of data, there could be 61 or so pages exported, when in reality only a page worth of data is displaying.

Is there an easy way to continue having the array formula applied across a large range, while limiting the print function to only apply to pages containing data that is returned from the array formula?

I'm also using the **Format > AutoFit Row Height** function to adjust the row height in accordance to the length of the returned items, but at the moment I think I have to do this manually every time I return data. Is there a way of applying that automatically to adjust around the content of the page?

Many thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: The print area in Excel is static. So, there is no easy way out of this. You can merely write a VBA macro to determine the range which actually contains data and then set the print area to this `static` area before printing. But without VBA you are out of luck to make it seemingly "dynamic".

Comment: Thanks Ralph, had a feeling it wouldn't be an easy one. Hopeless with vba though, wouldn't know where to start...is anybody able to sugggest an approach?

Comment: You'll probably want to make sure that the `PrintArea` is set before someone prints. So, you might want to make use of `Workbook_BeforePrint`. If you are looking for relevant VBA code you just need to issue a search. The web and *StackOverflow* in particular are full of examples: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel-vba%5D+printarea

Comment: Off-topic, but do you get any speed issues? When running down a repeated array formula with just absolute fixed references, I would put the constant array result in a named Range: `IF((Sheet1!$C$3:$C$5998>=Crynodeb!$D$3)*(Sheet1!$C$3:$C$5998<=Crynodeb!$F$3)*(Sheet1!$V$3:$V$5998<>""),ROW(Sheet1!$V$3:$W$5998)-2)`, and then refer to that Named Range with the wrapper SMALL function etc.

Comment: It's a little laggy sometimes, but hasn't been a problem. I had wondered about this though, thanks for that - will look at implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to export the data to PDF via macro, we can just put everything you want into that one macro.

The macro needs to find the range that has values. From your example, I'm assuming there will always be data returned starting in A3; and then there will no blanks in Column A until the end of the data.

So, this macro starts at A3 and looks at each cell until it finds a blank value to determine where the data ends.

I'm also assuming you have a fixed number of columns of data. I can only see 2 columns so I've used that figure in macro. You can update the code where indicated to the actual number of columns.

Then, from A1 to the last row and column of the data, it autofits the rows and then saves that range as a PDF.

```
Public Sub SaveCopy()

Dim intLastRow As Integer

'Loops through column A to find last row with data
intLastRow = 3
Do While Cells(intLastRow + 1, 1).Value <> ""
    intLastRow = intLastRow + 1
Loop

'With the range of data...
'NOTE: REPLACE '2' WITH ACTUAL NUMBER OF COLUMNS OF DATA
With Range("A1", Cells(intLastRow, 2))

    'Ensure text is wrapping - required to autofit
    .WrapText = True

    'Autofit row height
    .Rows.AutoFit

    'Save as PDF
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=ThisWorkbook.FullName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

End With

End Sub
```

This is a basic export and will just save the PDF into the same location as the file and with the same filename (including the excel file extension) and just appends .PDF file extension.

There are various options for handling the filename and location of the PDF. With more information of what is required I could help provide a robust solution.

Alternatively, you can remove the line of code for exporting to PDF and replace it with just ".Select"

This will select the range of data and then you can manually save to PDF. Just use Save As... change the type to PDF, click Options and choose "Selection" in the "Publish what" section.

[image: Saving as PDFT]

If any of my assumptions are incorrect, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks Michael. In regards to the PDF quality, I've tried additional options in the save dialogue box before, but it seems to have very little impact on the image quality. It seems it's just not meant to be with excel!